# Sort objects with duplicate keys

Tags: c++, list

I need a long list of objects ordered by one of they're parameters. What is the fastest way to do this in C++? I need to be able to add and remove elements to this list and still be sorted by that specific parameter.

```
Class Foo {
private:
  int rank;
}
```

I want all my `Foo` objects to be listed in ascending order and *when a new one is added or deleted it should take the right spot in the order*. There can also be more than one object with the same `rank` so key-value is not possible.

Any idea how I can do this in C++? I was looking at [make_heap()](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/make_heap.html) but I'm not sure how to use it (or if it can be used) with objects.

Comment: Or rather std::set - unless you need to change the elements.

Comment: A map needs a unique key though, in my scenario it's possible that there are several objects where the parameter of the object I want to order by is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should probably define `operator<` for `Foo` (something like this)...

```
inline bool operator< (const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
  return lhs.rank < rhs.rank;
}
```

which will need to be declared as a friend of `Foo`'s:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  explicit Foo(int rank_init) : rank(rank_init) {}
  friend bool operator< (const Foo&, const Foo&);
 private:
  int rank;
};
```

Now you can create a `std::multiset<Foo>` which will keep the `Foo`s sorted ascending by `rank`, e.g.

```
std::multiset<Foo> foo_multiset;
foo_multiset.insert(Foo(5));  // 5
foo_multiset.insert(Foo(3));  // 3, 5
foo_multiset.insert(Foo(1));  // 1, 3, 5
foo_multiset.insert(Foo(3));  // 1, 3, 3, 5
size_t erased_count(foo_multiset.erase(Foo(3)));  // 1, 5 (erased_count == 2)
```

There are no guarantees however that this will be the "fastest" option in your particular case.  You'll need to profile for that.  Depending on the number of elements, the frequency of insert/erase operations, and the STL implementation, you could find that a sorted `std::vector<Foo>` better suits your needs.

Scott Meyers' [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) describes how this could be the case in Item 23.

Comment: How does that work, do I call operator before adding my object to the multiset? And what happens if two ranks are equal? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `multiset` uses `std::less` which uses `operator<` to determine the sort order.  You do not have to do anything other than define these as per my answer, and you're good to go.  `multiset` caters for multiple elements whose keys are equivalent, so you'll be able to keep multiple `Foo`s with identical ranks in the container.

Comment: One more question: does it matter for performance whether or not the objects in the multiset are ordered? I've made some changements to my model and I don't need them to be ordered anymore, I just need to quickly access items with the same key.

Comment: In this case, performance-wise you're probably better with [`std::unordered_multiset<Foo>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_multiset/), or if your compiler doesn't support this, [`boost::unordered_multiset<Foo>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/unordered.html).  These are a wee bit more complex to use than `std::multiset`; you'd have to define `operator==` instead of `operator<` and you'd also have to define a hash function for `Foo`.

Comment: I'll have a look at those. It seems that elements can't be changed once added to the set though. But I guess I can just remove and add again since these are small objects anyway

Comment: Well, that's true for `std::multiset` too since the elements are themselves the keys.  If you changed an element, it could affect where it should be placed in the container.  Your original question only mentioned add and remove.  If you *do* want to modify the elements in-situ, then `std::multimap` or `std::unordered_multimap` would be better options, assuming the part of `Foo` you wish to change is not the part which provides the key for the container (`rank` in your example).

Comment: Just recreating the object instead of changing it is not a problem in my case. I have one last question though: why is it necessary to extend the `operator==` if the order doesn't matter? Thanks a lot for all your help, it's bee, really useful to me.

Comment: Probably your best answer to this is to have a look through the boost documentation for [`unordered_multiset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/unordered.html), in particular, the part describing [Equality Predicates and Hash Functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html).  Basically, it's down to the fundamentally different way in which hash containers like `unordered_multiset` implement their lookup mechanisms compared to associative containers like `multiset`.