# unordered_multimap usage and operator overwriting

Tags: c++, implementation, unordered-map

I need to use an [`unordered_multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_multiset/) for my Note objects and the keys will be the `measureNumber` member of my objects. I'm trying to implement it [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098838/393964) but I'm stuck.

First off, I don't understand why I have to overwrite the `operator==` before I can use it. I'm also confused about why I need a hash and how to implement it. [In this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046922/c-unordered-multimap), none of those two things is done.

So based on the first example, this is what I have:

```
class Note {
private:
    int measureNumber;
public:
    inline bool operator== (const Note &noteOne, const Note &noteTwo);
}

inline bool Note::operator ==(const Note& noteOne, const Note& noteTwo){
    return noteOne.measureNumber == noteTwo.measureNumber;
}
```

I don't know how to implement the hash part though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::multimap` is based on a sorted binary tree, which uses a less-than operation to sort the nodes.

`std::unordered_multimap` is based on a hash table, which uses hash and equality operations to organize the nodes without sorting them.

The sorting or hashing is based on the key values. If the objects are the keys, then you need to define these operations. If the keys are of predefined type like `int` or `string`, then you don't need to worry about it.

The problem with your pseudocode is that `measureNumber` is private, so the user of `Note` cannot easily specify the key to the map. I would recommend making `measureNumber` public or rethinking the design. (Is measure number really a good key value? I'm guessing this is musical notation.)

```
std::multimap< int, Note > notes;
Note myNote( e_sharp, /* octave */ 3, /* measure */ 5 );
notes.insert( std::make_pair( myNote.measureNumber, myNote ) );
```

The objects can be keys *and* values at the same time, if you use `std::multiset` or `std::unordered_multiset`, in which case you would want to define the operator overload (and possibly hash). If `operator==` (or `operator<`) is a member function, then the left-hand side becomes `this` and the right-hand side becomes the sole argument. Usually these functions should be non-member friends. So then you would have

```
class Note {
private:
    int measureNumber;
public:
    friend bool operator< (const Note &noteOne, const Note &noteTwo);
}

inline bool operator <(const Note& noteOne, const Note& noteTwo){
    return noteOne.measureNumber < noteTwo.measureNumber;
}
```

This class could be used with `std::multiset`. To perform a basic lookup, you can construct a dummy object with uninitialized values except for `measureNumber` — this only works for simple object types.

Comment: And how would I construct the multimap, like this? `multimap<int,Note> noteMap;` And does the definition of the `operator<` function go in the header or in the implementation file?

Comment: @Sled OK, I hope this is what you're looking for. Need to go now, good luck!

Comment: I have getters and setters for the measureNumber so that's not really a problem. What I do realize now is that it's kind of hard to remove a specific note since they're mapped by measureNumber but I need this model for real time synthesis where I need to find the notes by measure as quickly as possible and this seems like a good way so far. (I've had to change things around way to many times) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Sled: You could put an upper limit of notes per measure (say, a million) and construct a note index from `measureNumber * 1000000 + indexInMeasure`. Then use `lower_bound` to find the notes in a particular measure, or use `find` to find (and remove) a particular note.

Comment: So if I want to find a note I calculate `measureNumber * 1000000 + indexInMeasure`? I don't really understand how the lower_bound part would work, to find notes within a measure though..

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good practice to use `Note` as the key *and* value like that.  You could change an element's `measureNumber` which would put it out of sync with the element's key.  Also, you're missing something like `std::make_pair()` in your `insert` call.

Comment: @Sled: `lower_bound( measureNumber * 1000000 )` would return an iterator to the first note in the measure, and then you can iterate over the sequence until you get to the next measure. It's true that this structure should perhaps not store the `Note` objects directly, but only pointers, if it doesn't really "own" them, especially if the measureNumber can be changed (which would require destroying and re-creating the object within the map). But you can work with this for now until it's clear what design would be better.

Comment: One more question: why are you using make_pair before adding a new row to the multimap? That makes them into one object while the multimap expects an int and a Note, no?

Comment: Also, how can I see, when iterating, if the current measure is over? Especially considering some measures can be empty, so I can't check if it's one measure higher than the current one..

Comment: @Sled: 1. The `insert` method always takes exactly one argument, so we have to combine the key and value with `make_pair`. The structure separates them again internally. 2. You can divide by a million and wait for the result to change. Just check if it's not equal, not specifically one higher. 3. There are many approaches, and this is almost certainly not the best for the whole scope of the program, so don't get hung up on details. Just make it work intuitively and then refine.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use an unordered_multimap for my Note objects and the keys
>   will be the measureNumber member of my objects.

OK - I'm not sure whether you're after a `multiset`, `unordered_multiset`, `multimap`, or `unordered_multimap`.  I know your title refers to `unordered_multimap`, but the link you provided leads to `unordered_multiset`.  There are a multitude of considerations which should be taken into account when choosing a container, but second-guessing which will be the best-performing without profiling is a risky business.

> I don't understand why I have to overwrite the operator== before I can use it.
>   I'm also confused about why I need a hash and how to implement it. 
>   In this example here, none of those two things is done.

You need the `operator==` and `std::hash` as they're used internally by `unordered_multimap` and `unordered_multiset`.  In the example you linked to, the key is of type `int`, so `operator==` and `std::hash<int>` are already defined.  If you choose to use `Note` as a key, you have to define these yourself.

I'd recommend starting with a `multiset` if you don't need to change the elements frequently.  If you *do* want to be able to change `Note`s without erasing and inserting, I'd recommend removing `measureNumber` as a member of `Note` and using a `multimap<int, Note>`.

If you feel an `unordered_` version of your container would better suit your needs, you still have the `set` vs `map` choice.  If you choose `unordered_multimap<int, Note>` (having removed `measureNumber` from `Note`), then as in your linked example, the key is `int`.  So you won't have to define anything special for this to work.  If you choose to keep `measureNumber` as a member of `Note` and use `unordered_multiset<Note>`, then `Note` is the key and so you need to do further work, e.g.

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_set>

class Note;  // Forward declaration to allow specialisation of std::hash<>

namespace std {
template<>
class hash<Note> {
public:
    size_t operator()(const Note &) const;  // declaration of operator() to
                                            // allow befriending by Note
};
}

class Note {
private:
    int measureNumber;
public:
    // functions befriended to allow access to measureNumber
    friend bool operator== (const Note &, const Note &);
    friend std::size_t std::hash<Note>::operator()(const Note &) const;
};

inline bool operator== (const Note &noteOne, const Note &noteTwo) {
    return noteOne.measureNumber == noteTwo.measureNumber;
}

std::size_t std::hash<Note>::operator()(const Note &note) const {
    return std::hash<int>()(note.measureNumber);
}
```

This lets you create and use `std::unordered_multiset<Note>`.  However, I'm not sure this *is* really what you need; you could even find that a sorted `std::vector<Note>` is best for you.  Further research and thought as to how you'll use your container along with profiling should give the best answer.